# C++ Crash Dumps on POSIX

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, posix, stack-trace, crash-dumps

I have a big C++ code (server for some application).
This application is big, and catch a crash per 2 months in average.
And i can't simulate this crash to catch her with `gdb`.

Is exists some cool api to analyze memory on crash dump (stacktrace, local vars)?

What is best way to catch stack corruption time?

Comment: Can you run valgrind on it?  Perhaps you can see evidence of things going wrong before they crash?

Comment: @Jeff Foster: I will try this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable core dumping, wait for it to crash. Then load the core into gdb and debug as usual.

`ulimit -c unlimited`

Comment: Is already set to unlimited, and binary is compiled with symbols, then i should have some dumps, where i can find this files?

Comment: @Svisstack The core should be in the working directory of the program. If the program doesn't change that it should be in the directory you run it from. It should be named core, or core.number (or using some similar scheme).

Comment: i don't have this files, i searched over /. Why i can't file this files?

Comment: I don't know why core files arent being created for you, but perhaps another option is to simply run your server under gdb directly? It's not ideal, but at the point of the crash you should return to the gdb prompt.  If the server is one you cannot keep a terminal open in for the two months it takes to crash, you can run it within a "screen" session if you have (or can get) that utility on the system.

Comment: Can't do this, server must working all time, i run this in bash while for wake-up after crash. This method is not solution for me, i will try turn on this dumps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do :
1. Unit test your code, and execute them using valgrind
2. enable core dumps (as Let_Me_Be said in his answer)